# Azure SDK 1.3 opens two browser windows (or tabs)

Tags: c#, azure

Why is it that when run I website using Azure SDK 1.3 it opens two browser windows (or tabs) despite the fact that I have only defined one end point:

```
<Sites>
  <Site name="Web">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
</Sites>
```

What do I have to do to get just one browser window appearing when I run (using F5) my Azure application from Visual Studio?

Comment: FWIW, I can verify that I have the same experience, but if I run without debugging (Ctrl+F5) I only get a single browser window. BTW I'm running Firefox, so I don't know if the same issue occurs with IE.

Comment: I am runnig it in Firefox also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it looks this was a clear Azure SDK bug. Now with August 2011 update, this error have disappeared. Only one browser window is now opened.

[Latest Azure SDK.](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/sdk/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a guess and say that you've configured Chrome as your default browser in Visual Studio.

I got the same result with Chrome; when I switched the default browser to IE inside Visual Studio, only one browser launched when I started my app.

Oddly, with Firefox was my default browser, Visual Studio launched one instance of Firefox and one instance of Chrome.

This looks like a bug or odd configuration glitch that we both share inside Visual Studio and/or the Azure 1.3 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

If you enabled HTTPS in you CloudService, it will launch two browser windows one for http ad another for https. If this is the case go to your *.CloudService project and double click on the role you are starting(inside Roles folder). 
It should open a configuration window where you can set Launch browser for http and/or https.

Comment: I have already check it. I have checked only HTTP endpoint (HTTPS checkbox is disabled anyway). Any other ideas?