# Azure DevFabric launching multiple tabs when debugging

Tags: azure

I've created an Azure application that I'm running in my local fabric. Everything was fine until I added a second HTTPS endpoint to my serviceDefinition.csdef file. Lo and behold, the next time I tried to run in the local fabric, it launched FOUR tabs in my browser, all pointing to the same page.

I backed out my changes and went with the single Endpoint. Now the dev fabric is launching two tabs each time I run in debug. My ServiceDefinition.csdef file is listed below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="...blahblah...." xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition">
  <WebRole name="blahblah" vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="HttpIn" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="HttpIn" protocol="http" port="80" />
    </Endpoints>
    <Imports>
      <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
    </Imports>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

When I right click on my web role in the Azure project and expand "Launch in Browser", I only have Http checked. Any ideas?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584047/azure-1-3-sdk-open-two-browser-windows-or-tabs

Answer (score 2):

Here is one thing to check.  Right click your Web Role in Solution Explorer under your Cloud Service project and go to the Properties page.  On the Configuration tab, there is a section called Startup action where you specify what endpoints to launch a browser for, HTTP and/or HTTPS.  Make sure only one of them are checked.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this problem but it only happens when my default browser is chrome.  If I set IE as my default browser only 1 tab opens.